# How can I change the aspect ratio constraint value from code?

Tags: ios, constraints, aspect-ratio

I have given an aspect ratio constraint of 1:2 for an imageView in my xib. I have created an IBOutlet for the constraint. Now I need to change the aspect ratio to 1:1 for certain criteria. I want to know whether there is any way to change the constraint's multiplier value other than removing the old constraint and putting in a new one??

Comment: You can change the constraint's `multiplier` property.  For an aspect ratio of 1:1, the value would be 1

Comment: But its 'read-only' right?

Comment: Huh yeah.  I didn't look at that - I have only ever modified the constant before.

Comment: If you only want to have the two different aspect ratios you may be able to install two constraints and have one active, one inactive.  To change the aspect ratio, flip the active/inactive states.  You are still effectively removing/installing a constraint but it is simple code

Comment: That is another alternative.. but I really want to know whether it is possible to edit that aspect-ratio constraint...

Answer (score 1):

I think its not possible other than the 'remove and replace constraint' method.

Comment: Well.. it is possible to change the constant value of normal constraints.. there should be some way right?

Answer (score 1):

The multiplier is a get only property. So you can change only constant and isActive.

The constant for this constraint changes the height. If constant == width, then the height would be zero.

It's better to add height and width constraints and change them in code.