# How to change aspectRatio of IBOutlet for a view programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Okay here is my constraints.
[image: Applied Contraints]

The view is aligned centreX and centreY and has leading, trailing, top & bottom as >= 0.
It also has another constraint of aspectRatio.
Now I have created the `@IBOutlet` of aspectRation constraint.

```
@IBOutlet weak var contentViewAspectRatio: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

The problem is I don't know how to change the aspectRatio programmatically.

```
if value {
    //Change aspect ratio to 16/9
} else {
    //Change aspect ratio to 19.5/9
}
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could create 2 constraints with your 2 values, and activate/deactivate them depending on `value`. Make priority for one just lower than the other one, or you'll have a conflict in InterfaceBuilder See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773182/how-can-i-change-the-aspect-ratio-constraint-value-from-code you can't change the multiplier though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the aspect ratio means changing the multiplier of the constraint which is a read-only so you need to deactivate that constraint and create a new 1 with a new multiplier

```
let newCon = contentViewAspectRatio.addConstraintWithMul(0.3)
parentViewOfConstraint.removeConstraint(contentViewAspectRatio)
parentViewOfConstraint.addConstraint(newCon)
view.layoutIfNeeded()
contentViewAspectRatio = newCon
```

---

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    func addConstraintWithMul(_ multiplier: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
        return NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.firstItem!, attribute: self.firstAttribute, relatedBy: self.relation, toItem: self.secondItem, attribute: self.secondAttribute, multiplier: multiplier, constant: self.constant)
    }
}
```

Another option is to create 2 constraints with 2 different aspects and play with their active / priority state in case you have a limited and know number of aspects

Comment: Later option seems to be working, will let you know